# PostAsJsonAsync it's not posting

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

i had created a code to insert a product item into my API, but its not working, i had tried to do manually using the PostMan and just made it, the status is allways 201 - created, im using .net 6

````
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json;
using WebApplication1.Data;
using WebApplication1.Models;

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {

                Item_Produtos item = new Item_Produtos();
                item.Id = 10;
                item.Produto_Id = 109;
                item.PedidoVenda_Id = 15283;
                item.qtdItem = 1;
                item.vlPreco = 109;
                item.Item_Obs = "";
                item.Opcao_Obs = "Tamanho:M=1;|Cor:Especial=1;|";
                item.Store_Id = 27;
                item.vlSubTotal = 109;

                using HttpClient client = new()
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("api/adress-here")
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("carrinho", item);
                Console.WriteLine(
                $"{(response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "Success" : "Error")} - {response.StatusCode}");
            } ```
````

Comment: Although this is not the solution to your problem, why are you making two HttpClient (s)?

Comment: Install a proxy like Fiddler, and then run your app and the PostMan app. Once you have captured a success and a failure, compare the requests in Fiddler to see where the difference is.

Comment: i just did it, and they are doing the same request, but i notie something, when i use the text mode in the postman, still return the 201 code, but when i use the get method it's not found

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by separating some steps, at first converting into a Json then into a string Content, and then instead of use the PostAsJsonAsync  i used the PostAsync with the new format

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json;
using WebApplication1.Data;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using System.Text;



            using HttpClient client = new(){
                BaseAddress = new Uri("api/adress-here")
            };

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("carrinho", data);
```